# Не запускается функция OnCollisionEnter

Tags: unity3d

```
BoxCollider boxCollider;
private float deltaY;

void Start()
{
    boxCollider = GetComponent<BoxCollider>();
}
private void Update()
{
    transform.position = new Vector2(transform.position.x, transform.position.y - (speed * Time.deltaTime));
    if (Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") != 0)
    {
        deltaY = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        transform.position = new Vector2(transform.position.x + (deltaY * speed_horizontal * Time.deltaTime), transform.position.y);
    }
    if (Input.GetAxis("Vertical") < 0)
        speed = 5f;
    else
        speed = 0.5f;
}
private void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
{
    Debug.Log(2);
}
```

Вообщем есть два объекта 3D. Сам проект 2D. Два объекта касаются друг друга. К обоим присоединен BoxCollaider и по размеру также он подогнан. По параметру Z объекты на одном уровне. В режиме 3D это явно видно. К одному из объектов присоединен данный скрипт. Но по какой то причине строчка Debug.Log(2); не выполняется (консоль вообще пустая, даже ошибок нет). Вопрос: Почему не выполняется функция OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)?

Comment: Мне что-то не оч нравится как вы 3д объекты крутите вектором2

Comment: Я его перемещаю вектором 2, т.к. по оси z мне нет необходимости его менять

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Хоть у какого - то из этих объектов есть RigidBody? Ибо для соприкосновения необходимо, чтобы у всех были BoxCollider-ы и хоть у одного RigidBody